# Is being gay the opposite of being straight, or just different?

Tags: ethics

Caveat: one of the basic ethics beliefs I have is that right and wrong are opposites, such that wrong just is whatever cancels out what's right. It is impossible, on this view, to establish free-floating wrong; you always have to start from something right and then show what cancels it out to show what's wrong, there.

From this POV, I have had a hard time understanding how being/acting gay could be wrong by itself. Gay actions would have to cancel out straight ones to be wrong as such, but they don't do that. They're just different.

I considered formal opposition, too: things contrary in a more abstract way, but again I can't see that being gay is the formal opposite of being straight. Maybe it has to do with how people sometimes say that men and women are opposites (which also sounds false to me, btw)?

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by opposite? Also, what does this have to do with right vs wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your questions 

Comment: I'm not inclined to write a formal answer to this (as it would entail detailing some viewpoints I find objectionable, even if they are notable from the point of view of the history of philosophy) but you could look at Kant's take on the matter. https://www.jstor.org/stable/27744817 "Kant repeatedly says that through each of the unnatural vices, a person degrades herself below the level of animals" (MS 425; L 159, 170). He calls homosexual sex, bestiality, and masturbation "the most disgraceful and the most degrading [conduct] of which the human being is capable" (L 170)."

Comment: What does "wrong just is whatever cancels out what's right" mean? Murder is wrong, but what does it "cancel", giving birth? Completing your argument, we can not have free-floating right either, we always have to present a "canceling" pair of "opposites". There is an old theory of [evil as privation of good](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concept-evil/#DuaPriTheEvi), but the "canceling" language does not make much sense even there.

Comment: Murder cancels out whatever good a person is doing as a living being, up to the good of living itself (supposing this is good). And yes, there is always the opposite of corruptive or destructive acts for any positive good/right act (I'm waiving the deontological/teleological dichotomy for present purposes). Corruption would be cancelling out good properties, destruction cancels out good substance... But setting all this metaphysics aside, I still don't get how non-natural converts to antinatural, when it comes to expressions of being gay?

Comment: Formal opposition here would be like pain and pleasure or sadness and happiness re: a utilitarian outlook.

Comment: You're not missing anything. There's nothing wrong to being gay.

Comment: There's also nothing "non-natural" with being gay.

Comment: Being gay myself, I tend to agree with those comments but I also like playing devil's advocate so I just would like to know how the antithesis is supposed to work, here.

Comment: Murder is not the only way of "canceling" good things in a person. In fact, any talk of "corruption" and "opposites" presupposes some spectrum of variation along which an attribute is "corrupted" and the "opposite" is taken. One can easily come up with spectra of behaviors that go from "natural" matrimony to various "opposites" that "corrupt" and "cancel" its "good" attributes, sex for money, adultery, gay sex, beastiality, etc. Not that there is a good case that monogamous matrimony is particularly "natural", but that is what it is taken to be in the natural law tradition.

Comment: I don't get the question, then. According to your "basic ethics belief" you can't find what's wrong with being gay. But it's in accordance with your own position about the subject. On the other hand, some other people might consider it is wrong to be gay, but if they do not share your basic ethics belief, which is imho very personal to you, then there is no contradiction on their side either.

Comment: The argument would be: Y is wrong if it is contrary to something right X. Even if being straight is right, being gay is not contrary to that, ergo... So my question is whether gay and straight are contraries or just different.

Comment: How about bi people?

Comment: Bisexuality seems to be evidence that gay and straight are not contrary, since they don't cancel out like matter and antimatter but can coexist as bisexuality in individual persons.

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased the question as, "Is being gay the same as being antistraight?" But I suspect that would not have been much clearer...

Comment: I guarantee you Kant was a big masturbator. His brisk walk every day would not have been enough to work off the sexual tension, especially when he was a young man. This opens a new idea for historians to explore. We know now that the young JS Bach was a lusty teenager in all directions. He was a knife fighter too. Enjoyed pulling his knife out.

Comment: Bisexual is a Hegelian thing. Given enough time and development these people will have sex with everyone and everything. It amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say I question the moral precept you outline. I mean, why would we define 'wrong' as that which cancels out 'right', without circularly defining 'right' as that which cancels out 'wrong'? You seem to have given an odd ontological primacy to 'right', as though it's pre-given, and pre-known.

Just so it's said...

That aside, it's worth remembering that the original (ancient Hebrew) aversion wasn't to homosexuality *per se*, but to [onanism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onanism): wasting semen that ought to be used for reproduction. The ancient world viewed reproduction as analogous to planting seed in fertile ground; (male) semen contained the entire active potential for human life, seeking out an appropriately fallow (female) field to lie in. Wasting semen was like tossing perfectly good grain on rocks or sand: wasteful at best, an invitation to famine at worst. In an age when child mortality could be as high as 50% and maternal mortality could be over 25%, anti-onanism made a certain practical sense. Thus (to use your system) onanism — and by extension homosexuality — cancels out the positive good of potential childbirth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *fully* understand the formal backing for your philosophical system, so if it's OK with you, I'm going to interpret it as a mostly utilitarian system. In particular, you say that an action is wrong if it cancels out something right, so I'm going to formalize that by defining some set of happiness, freedom or fulfillment as "utility" and you see actions as wrong if they reduce that utility.

It's hard to see how the existence of homosexual relationships would reduce anyone's utility, particularly because it provides significant happiness to the couple involved, unless your definition of "utility" explicitly calls out heterosexual relationships (or some proxy thereof). But perhaps some people do have such a definition of utility, particularly if they find themselves both utilitarian and homophobic.

I think more likely the homophobic individuals that you want to understand have a deontological ethical framework (could be theistic or atheistic), and think of acts as right or wrong in themselves. With this framework, it is easy to judge homosexuality as wrong, because for those people it is simply taken as axiomatic that it is wrong. But many other people use this framework and don't judge it as wrong. So if you encounter this kind of person, who is thinking rationally about their ethical framework, you might want to ask them why they take it as axiomatic. (If it's theistic and Christian, I often try to highlight that being homosexual is an immutable part of oneself rather than a choice, and that God loves everyone, therefore God must love anyone regardless of their sexual orientation).

Finally, the most likely option is that the homophobic individuals are simply not being rational, and are reacting instinctively. Honestly, this is how I find most people. And the most effective way to understand it is that they are simply only comfortable with things that are familiar, and if they grew up in a straight household with straight friends, then gay couples are unfamiliar. In which case, I find the most successful tact to be sharing stories of how gay couples are happy, healthy and produce healthy children (if desired), which eventually will make it more familiar to them.

*Note: I can't claim to speak for all, most or even any other gay people. Nor for people that are homophobic, so I'm making up their rationales.*

Answer (score 1):

The idea of opposites necessarily "cancelling out" to nothing is unclear and unhelpful. For example yin and yang are opposites yet together they create wholeness. Also, in some schools of thought male and female are indeed seen as opposites, for example the male being upright and the female horizontal. c.f. also the horrendous *Men are from Mars, Women are from Venus* nonsense. Again, they can hardly be said to cancel each other out.

But having said that, your critique of ethical arguments for homophobia is correct. Ethics arise, as everything intrinsic to humanity does, as an evolutionary aid to survival. If it helps the Hom. Sap. gene pool to survive then it becomes felt as good, but if it threatens society then it becomes felt as bad. Homosexuality is widespread in nature - Geese and lions were among the first creatures where it was documented, and there are plenty more, including fish. So it clearly brings significant evolutionary benefit. Therefore only blind prejudice can prevent us from feeling it as good.

In human culture, many of our most creative talents have been gay. One may hazard that this is because gays tend to be less encumbered by families, so over time creativity has found more effective expression there than among heterosexuals. But that argument must be tempered by its apparently untenable implication that fish, geese and lions benefit from a strong gene pool for creative thinking. The evolutionary benefits of homosexuality remain an active topic of scientific research.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that yin and yang are complementary rather than contrary? But maybe then "opposite" is the category into which complementarity and contrariety both fall, and I have been misspeaking...

Comment: @KristianBerry "Opposite" and "complementary" have different meanings in different contexts, they are not very precise words to use for defining other concepts. One might say that yin and yang are complementary precisely because they are contrary; "To conceive an idea is also to conceive its opposite", thus one cannot have the one without the other.

Answer (score 1):

In talking about sexuality we are firmly in the natural world, in which case the idea of "opposites" or "cancelling out" makes little sense.

Clearly we can talk about day and night or fire and water as "opposites," but this is metaphorical. Things in the natural world do not and cannot cleanly sum to zero.

In the realm of free consciousness, opposites may be best described in terms of incompatible decisions, where acting upon one possibility forsakes or eliminates another possibility.

Here, the opposition would be individual not social, as when a person decides between homosexuality and the opposed practice of heterosexuality. From the idealized standpoint of a future outcome or irreversible "becoming" the choices are mutually exclusive and "opposed," the one "cancelling out" the other.

But this only leads us back into relativism, unless we apply some version of Kant's categorical morality. We might argue, with Kant, that homosexuality is internally conflicted because it is a course of spirit that will not reproduce or perpetuate its being.

This, in turn, shows the limits of Kantian universalism. Unconstrained heterosexuality inevitably enters a Malthusian spiral that may be "internally conflicted" for the species as a whole, environmentally self-negating.

Moreover, the direction of all energies and resources into reproduction and exponentially increasing offspring leaves little energy for the sublimated pursuits of "higher" attainments. We see this in the fact that so many pivotal figures, from Plato and Jesus to Kant himself were not "family" men.

No matter the "natural" imperatives, a sublimating escape from the nexus of heterosexual desires and reproduction, from the Schopenhauerian "will," appears essential to the development of creative consciousness, held by many to be the highest good.

Comment: If things in the natural world do not and cannot cleanly sum to zero, what is the relationship between matter and antimatter? But this is another good answer, though I stick with the one I ✔️'d as the most fitting (it depends implicitly on belief in sins of omission, which belief I don't exactly share, but regardless...).

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure about ontology of matter-antimatter, but I believe total mutual negation would violate the "inviolable" first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Another counter to my POV is: acts can be right under one description but seem wrong under another; and my POV effectively rules out unsolvable moral dilemmas. I accept these implications, though. Re: antimatter, the mass can be 100% converted to energy, and there is the great mystery of why there is so much less antimatter in the universe than symmetry would indicate; but I don't think violations of thermodynamics are involved.